# JoltTransformJson: Transform JSON Array with and add static value to each item from a FlowFile attribute

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I need to transform a JSON response from one time-series DB and output it to as a response in a new format.
Having an input JSON array, I need to transform it with JoltTransformJson (NiFi) and add a key-value for each item from a FlowFile attribute.

This is my input JSON:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2020-04-29T07:46:20.558731Z",
      "Value": 66.0303
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2020-04-29T07:46:35.558731Z",
      "Value": 69.11584
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired output should be:

```
[{
    "sensor_id": "xyz",
    "sample_time": "2020-04-29T07:46:20.558731Z",
    "sample_value": 66.0303
}, {
    "sensor_id": "xyz",
    "sample_time": "2020-04-29T07:46:35.558731Z",
    "sample_value": 69.11584
}]
```

where sensor_id is a FlowFile attribute...
I came across to this spec:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "Items": {
            "*": {
                "@Timestamp": "[#2].sample_time",
                "@Value": "[#2].sample_value",
                "${sensor_id}": "[#2].sensor_id"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

But I cannot get the sensor_id in the output json.... instead, this is what I get:

```
[{
    "sample_time": "2020-04-29T07:46:20.558731Z",
    "sample_value": 66.0303
}, {
    "sample_time": "2020-04-29T07:46:35.558731Z",
    "sample_value": 69.11584
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've managed to project the ${sensor_id} into the output json, what was missing is #, so the final spec will be:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "Items": {
            "*": {
                "@Timestamp": "[#2].sample_time",
                "@Value": "[#2].sample_value",
                "#${sensor_id}": "[#2].sensor_id"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Now, I've found that the Timestamp returned from my time-series DB is not exact what I need it to be. Instead I would like to convert it to integer timestamp (epoch sinse 1970)... Any idea how this can be achieved?